# Auto install and enable Excel Add-in using Setup Factory

Tags: excel, installation, add-in, vba

I have some VBA code and saved it as Excel Add-in. I need a method to install this Excel Add-in automatically. I want to create an installer so that my users can just run the installer to install the add-in.

I'm following [this guide](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/AddinsAndSetupFactory.asp) to install add-ins automatically.

But I don't understand how to add script using Setup Factory as the guide. For example, how do I insert this script using Setup Factory?

```
--Check whether Excel is opened.
sValues = Window.EnumerateTitles(true);

--Next line has SetupFactory 8 code
--for iCount, sValue in sValues do

for iCount, sValue in pairs(sValues) do
    if String.Find(sValue, "Microsoft Excel", 1, true)>0 then                   
        Dialog.Message("Error", "First close Microsoft Excel."..
                        String.Char(10)..String.Char(10)..
                        "Uninstaller will now abort.",
                        MB_OK, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        -- Make sure the process ends with a value other than 0
        -- so the uninstall can be performed again.
        Application.Exit(EXIT_REASON_USER_ABORTED);
    end;    
end;
```

Comment: Is this a VSTO Add-In or an Add-In created in VBA? I use Advanced Installer 9.0 to install my add-ins(Especially the ones created in VBA). It lets me create professional looking setups for the Add-In. If you do not want that kind of setup then you can create and Excel file and in the Workbook_Open Event install the Add-In as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Tasks Window select Actions ->On Startup and insert the script. The other script compomenents need to be inserted in the other Actions windows.